# How to set a duration for requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, requestanimationframe

[requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is good solution to creating javascript based animations. But i can not set a duration for this function. I want to play animations for a certain time. I tried some fps solutions but these are not smooth.

How can i fill this water in x seconds?
[image]

```js
const water = document.querySelector('.water')
let scale = 0

const fillGlass = () => {
  scale += 0.01
  water.style.transform = `scaleY(${scale})`

  if (scale <= 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(fillGlass)
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(fillGlass)
```

```css
.glass {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 12px
}

.water {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #BBDEFB;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

```html
<div class="glass">
  <div class="water"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: simple animation like this you can just write it in `css`'s [keyframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes). that way you will have more control.

Comment: keep in mind, different monitors have different frame rate, so `requestAnimationFrame` will run quick or slow depend on the monitors. for example, let's say you set 2 seconds to finish the animation. 120fps monitors might finish the animation in 1 seconds and 60fps monitors might finish the animation in 3 seconds.

Comment: @Layhout So i can not use this. Can you suggest any other solution?

Comment: may i know why must it be done with js?

Comment: @Layhout because i will play with, start/stop, instant fill and instant empty actions. Yes i know i can start/stop animation with animaton-play-state css property, but i can not animate fill, and empty actions. You can check here: https://jsfiddle.net/dhuj7x0w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you can control it with `animation-duration`. If you want to add dynamic value, I have just added a parameter to pass value to CSS

```css
.glass {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 12px
}

.water {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #BBDEFB;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: var(--value);
}

@keyframes animation {
  from { transform:scaleY(0) }
  to { transform:scaleY(1) }
}
```

```html
<div class="glass">
  <div class="water" style='--value:20s'></div>
</div>
```

you can change `--value` in HTML, it will affect on CSS

### As per your need, in JS

```js
const water = document.querySelector('.water')
let scale = 0
let time = 2000  // 20 second * 100 

 const myInterval = setInterval(()=> {
  scale += 1/time
  water.style.transform = `scaleY(${scale})`
  if (scale >= 1) {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
}, 10);
```

```css
.glass {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 12px
}

.water {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #BBDEFB;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

```html
<div class="glass">
  <div class="water"></div>
</div>
```

### More Functions

```js
const start = document.querySelector('.start')
const stop = document.querySelector('.stop')
const fill = document.querySelector('.fill')
const empty = document.querySelector('.empty')
const water = document.querySelector('.water')


let scale = 0
let time = 2000 // 20 second * 100 
let myInterval;

start.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    scale += 1 / time
    water.style.transform = `scaleY(${scale})`
    if (scale >= 1) {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
  }, 10);
})

stop.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(myInterval);
})

fill.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scale = 1
  water.style.transform = `scaleY(${scale})`

})

empty.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scale = 0
  water.style.transform = `scaleY(${scale})`
})
```

```css
.glass {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 12px
}

.water {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #BBDEFB;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="start">Start</button>
<button type="button" class="stop">Stop</button>
<button type="button" class="fill">Instant Fill</button>
<button type="button" class="empty">Instant Empty</button>

<div class="glass">
  <div class="water"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. This animation is not smooth.

Comment: @user10633395 I have edited the JS code check it

Answer (score 0):

Defining simple animation like this is always better with pure CSS, also in this case, it gives you more control over the animation itself.

```
.water {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #BBDEFB;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  animation-name: animation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes animation {
  from { transform:scaleY(0) }
  to { transform:scaleY(1) }
}
```

Comment: Hello. CSS is easy and working solution but i need with only JS.

Answer (score 0):

For animation and smoothness you can divide the scale value by duration you want

```
const water = document.querySelector('.water')
let scale = 0
let time = 5000 //in seconds 1000=1sec
let duration = 100/time;
const fillGlass = () => {
  scale += duration;
  if(scale > 1){
    scale = 1;
  }
  water.style.transform = `scaleY(${scale})`
  if (scale <= 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(fillGlass)
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(fillGlass)
```

Comment: Thanks but it breaks the smooth animation.

Comment: based on your solution, how long does it take to finish the animation? if OP want the animation to last 10 seconds, how do they achieve it using your solution?